# Scroll View offset not working properly in React-native

Tags: react-native

i want to update the offset when clik on button in my screen..I try many time but not get this the code is given below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry,Alert,ScrollView, Image, Dimensions, Text,View,TouchableOpacity,StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
class Pagination extends Component {
   count() {
    this.refs._scrollView.scrollProperties.contentOffset.x=this.refs._scrollView.scrollProperties.contentOffset.x+{width:Dimensions.get('window').width*1.00};
  } 
  render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView  ref={(scrollView) => { _scrollView = scrollView; }} horizontal={true} pagingEnabled={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false} onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
          <View
          style={{backgroundColor: '#3498db',width:Dimensions.get('window').width*1.00, height:Dimensions.get('window').height*1.00}}
          >
          < Image source={require('./flag/f1.jpg')}
           />
           <Text style={{padding:20,fontSize:30}}>Page1</Text>
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.count()}}
               >
           <View style={styles.ForwardOrBackward}>
           <Image
             style={styles.button}
              source={require('./flag/arrow.png')}
              />
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
           <View
           style={{backgroundColor: '#e67e22',width:Dimensions.get('window').width*1.00, height:Dimensions.get('window').height*1.00}}
           >
          <Image source={require('./flag/f1.jpg')} />
          <Text style={{padding:20,fontSize:30}}>Page2</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.count()} }>
           <View style={styles.ForwardOrBackward}>
           <Image
             style={styles.button}
              source={require('./flag/arrow.png')}
              />
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View
          style={{backgroundColor: '#f39c12', width:Dimensions.get('window').width*1.00, height:Dimensions.get('window').height*1.00}}
          >
          <Image source={require('./flag/f1.jpg')} />
          <Text style={{padding:20,fontSize:30}}>Page3</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.count()} } >
           <View style={styles.ForwardOrBackward}>
           <Image
             style={styles.button}
              source={require('./flag/arrow.png')}
              />
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View
          style={{backgroundColor: '#1abc9c',width:Dimensions.get('window').width*1.00, height:Dimensions.get('window').height*1.00}}
          >
          <Image source={require('./flag/f1.jpg')} />
          <Text style={{padding:20,fontSize:30}}>Page4</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.count()} } >
          <View style={styles.ForwardOrBackward}>
           <Image
             style={styles.button}
              source={require('./flag/arrow.png')}
              />
              </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View
          style={{backgroundColor: '#8e44ad', width:Dimensions.get('window').width*1.00, height:Dimensions.get('window').height*1.00}}
          >
          <Image source={require('./flag/f1.jpg')} />
          <Text style={{padding:20,fontSize:30}}>Page5</Text>
          <View style={styles.ForwardOrBackward}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.count()} } >
           <Image
             style={styles.button}
              source={require('./flag/arrow.png')}
              />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button :{
    height:60,
    width:60,
    borderRadius:30,
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center'
  },
  ForwardOrBackward:{
    alignItems:'center',
    justifyContent:'center' 
  }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Pagination', () => Pagination);
```

Here is a touchable opacity button i want to move the page when click on button but with this page not move to next page when click on button this function call

```
count() {
        this.refs._scrollView.scrollProperties.contentOffset.x=this.refs._scrollView.scrollProperties.contentOffset.x+{width:Dimensions.get('window').width*1.00};
      }
```

check it if syntax error in this function